# Refresh lwc component on record save

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning web component that it's data needs to be updated whenever the record is saved.

Is it possible to trigger a function\component refresh when the record is save?

Comment: refreshApex ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

Comment: I added a [variant of this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274390/how-to-get-an-lwc-component-on-a-record-page-to-refresh-when-that-page-is-update) with detail for my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using standard lightning components like [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) or [record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) or [getRecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) - All of them use lightning-data-services. So, if the same record is updated in one place, it will be automatically updated in all other places.

However, if you are call [Apex Method Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex), you can use [refreshApex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex)

---

**ADDED**

@Dana, as shown in the [How to get an LWC component on a record page to refresh when that page is updated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274390/how-to-get-an-lwc-component-on-a-record-page-to-refresh-when-that-page-is-update/274434?noredirect=1#comment414286_274434), it works fine for record update anywhere (for lightning data service)

Comment: I have the same scenario - the user edits the data via the page for the record and saves the update. I then have an LWC on a tab in the record page and it doesn't get refreshed. The component has nothing to do with the editing of the record, but appears on the same flexipage. It doesn't get updated when the record's details update.

Comment: @PhilW, I just checked exactly the scenario you told. I used `record-edit-form` and its updating when updated from record details. Can you pls create a question in detail if what I did is not correct?

Comment: @salesforce-sas The specific scenario is that i have a progress bar, that it's percentage should be updated once a few fields are not blank. So there is a calculation function that should run every time a record is saved.

Comment: @DanaGriff can you edit the question and give more info and codesnippets?

Comment: @Pranay jaiswal There is no snippet because i dont know how to trigger a function on record save.

Comment: As the documentation says, you just have to add a button to the form to fire the submit event that saves the fields on the database. You can catch that event in your controller (and even prevent it from being fired). It says: "Include a lightning-button component with type="submit" to automatically save any changes in the input fields when the button is clicked." That means you can use an `onclick` attribute on that button, and handle the event on your controller. The form component itself also fires other events like "load", "success" which you can use as triggers to fire the refresh one.

Comment: @Renato Oliveira what button? i'm talking about any record change. i'm not updating the record in my component.

Comment: @salesforce-sas it still doesnt answer my question. When the record is saved, i want to run function foo(). how is it possible?

Comment: Is it being saved from somewhere in record page? and you want to invoke function in your lwc component?

Comment: i actually found the solution from the post you added. i have getRecord wired. so whenever the page is saved, getRecord is invoked. i just called the calculation function from there. thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes @DanaGriff, Thats why I added it

Answer (score 2):

We can use combination of **getRecord** and **wiredMethod** to achieve this.
getRecord is called when record is saved & then you can chain a wired method inside it.
**LastModifiedDate** is used to chain these two since it gets updated every time record is saved.

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
    import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import someMethod from '@salesforce/apex/SomeCtrl.someMethod';
    export default class SomeCustomComponent extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @track account;
        lastModifiedDate;
    
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ 'Account.Name', 'Account.Phone' ] })
        getaccountRecord({ data, error }) {
            console.log('accountRecord => ', data, error);
            if (data) {
                this.account = data;
                this.lastModifiedDate = data.lastModifiedDate;
            } else if (error) {
                console.error('ERROR => ', JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }
        
        error;
        @wire(someMethod, {recordId : '$recordId', lastModifiedDate : '$lastModifiedDate'})
        wiredSomeMethod({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {
                // code goes here
            } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is bypassing any cache hit by varying the wire parameters. Use of last modified is good because the cache key will still be the same if the record didn't change, but since this is in the context of an update it will always be a cache miss. Be aware that this can proliferate a lot of redundant cache entries in the client and really is a bit of a fiddle than a robust solution. IMHO the right way to work is to avoid use of wire in such a scenario.