# Reload/refresh just a LWC without reloading all record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh

I have a LWC included inside the Case Record Page. I need that when I edit an element (I mean, when I **update a record**) in the LWC Salesforce does refresh just for the isolated LWC and not all the Case Record Page.

For example, if I use `window.location.reload()` I get the refresh, but it impacts all the page and reload it. I want to reload the specific record and its view in the LWC without reloading all page.

I tried with `refreshApex` but it does not work. Any idea?

CODE:

JS:

```
invokeEditComment(){
        editCommentary({commentary: this.commentaryEdited, serviceId: this.serviceId, caseId: this.recordId})
        .then(() => {
            this.showNotify(this.title, 'Edited', 'success');
            this.showEditCommentModal = false;
            this.showSpinner = false;
            //Is in this point in which I want to make the refresh. ⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️
            //return refreshApex(this.propuestaMetadata);
            //window.location.reload();

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.showNotify(this.title, GEN_ADM_MSG_ERR, 'warning');
        });
    }
```

CONTROLLER APEX METHOD:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void editCommentary(String commentary, String serviceId, String caseId)  {
        List<Services__c> serv = [SELECT Id,Comments__c, CaseId__c 
                                                   FROM Services__c
                                                   WHERE CaseId__c = :caseId];
        serv [0].Comments__c= commentary;
        update serv ;
    }
```

[image]

Blue zone is a Case Action that calls a flow, in which a screen contains the LWC. I want to refresh just the BLUE ZONE, and not all the page. Result must be like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi. You need to provide some detail here because it isn't clear what "edit an element" is and in what way refreshApex wasn't working. Add some code snippets and a clearer explanation of what you mean. Please [edit] to add this.

Comment: I edited. I mean when I update a record. For example, I have a LWC inside the Case Record Page that gets Services__c CustomObject and let you edit them and update them. When I update, I want user sees the records edited without reloading all Case Record Page. If Services__c has a field Comments__c, and it's 'A' and user changes it to 'B', I want that user sees 'B' after editing just refreshing LWC that controls Services__c, without reloading all Case Record Page.

Comment: RefreshApex just does not work as implementing as I checked. I could put the code, but I wanted to know if there is another option.

Comment: The options entirely depend on a) what mechanism is used to update the record and b) how the LWC gets its data to show. This is why we need you to add detail. If your LWC uses the uiRecordApi then it should auto-refresh when the same record is modified elsewhere in the page, but I'm guessing you wrote your own apex method to get the data instead.

Comment: Yes, is the second way, I wrote my own apex method. So, I put the code.

Comment: what is invoking your `invokeEditComment` ?do you at least have your method being triggered when the record is edited?

Comment: onclick statement in HTML. Function works okay, the data is updated. But, if you see, I was using window.location.reload() that refresh all Record Page. I'd like to use something like thisLWC.reload() (I invent), I mean, a function that reloads just the LWC, and not all the page.

Comment: Are the Services__c currently shown in a related list component elsewhere in the page?

Comment: @PhilW, yes, I'll try to make a simple paint sketch to try to ilustrate it.

Comment: Good idea. Sorry, for clarity can you point out where else on the page the Services__c are shown, if they are also shown outside your LWC?

Comment: LWC just appears in the blue zone of the picture. There is a Related List of al Services__c created.

Comment: OK, so if the Services__c are only shown in the LWC then refreshApex is the correct approach. Can you [edit] to shown how `this.propuestaMetadata` is populated? (Also take a look at this [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/how-to-refresh-wired-service-getrecord-manually/279523#279523)).

Comment: Note that refreshApex applies to both imperative calls and wires that use cacheable methods on the org.

Comment: And other [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274390/how-to-get-an-lwc-component-on-a-record-page-to-refresh-when-that-page-is-update) to consider.

Comment: @PhilW I checked all of your questions, and I'm not sure what to do. ```this.propuestaMetadata``` contains this info : ```@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: SERVICE_OBJECT})``` . So, I guess I need to create @wire with the info of the service id that I'm editing?

Comment: The wire, above, isn't fetching the data, but rather information about the data (i.e. the schema metadata). Where are you fetching the list of Services__c records?

Comment: In another function that calls APEX METHOD that get list of Services__c.

Comment: Are you able to share that function that calls your apex method? Sounds like you're calling that apex method imperatively? Is that apex method `cacheable`?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use [the RefreshView API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html) now. Import `RefreshView` from `lightning/refresh` and dispatch that event.

```js
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
  method() {
    // this will tell the view to refresh its contents
    this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the below as you suggested and its working for first time , but when I revisit the component/tab where the component is called for the second time its not updating with the latest values . any suggestion on it ? Thanks You are able to use the RefreshView API now. Import RefreshView from lightning/refresh and dispatch that event. import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh"; export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement { method() { // this will tell the view to refresh its contents this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent()); }
}