# getrelatedlistrecords is not getting refreshed

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, wire, refreshapex, relatedrecord

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Histories',
        fields: '$fieldHistory',
    })
    wiredFieldHistory({data, error}){
        if (data) {
            this.fieldHistoryValue = data.records;
           // refreshApex(this.fieldHistoryValue);
           // this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());

            this.fieldHistoryValue.map( objHistry => {
                this.oldValue.push(
                    objHistry.fields.OldValue.value
                )
            }); 
           // refreshApex(this.oldValue);
           // this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent(this.oldValue));
            console.log('OldValue: '+JSON.stringify(this.oldValue));

           // getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
    
          //  refreshApex(this.fieldHistoryValue);
           // console.log('fieldHistoryValue: '+ JSON.stringify(this.fieldHistoryValue)); 
           // console.log('fieldHistoryValue1: '+ JSON.stringify(this.fieldHistoryValue[0].fields.OldValue)); 
           // this.oldValue = getFieldDisplayValue(data.records, `${this.stageField1}.OldValue`);
           this.newValue = getFieldValue(data.records[0], `${this.stageField1}.NewValue`);
            console.log('newValue: '+this.newValue);
            eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");

        }
        else if (error) {
            console.error('Error occurred retrieving Field History Record...' +JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }
```

i tried everything getRecordNotifyChange, refreshApex but nothing is working... i want this.oldValue to get updated... can anyone please help me in this, it would be really appreciated. field is getting updated from ui and not from lwc.. in lwc it just contain chevron and there is no click event

Comment: @salesforce-sas, can you help me in this, because you have similar issue here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274390/how-to-get-an-lwc-component-on-a-record-page-to-refresh-when-that-page-is-update/274434?noredirect=1#comment414286_274434